# Many to many relationship in hibernate deleting the join table data?

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, hibernate-mapping

i have many to many relationship in hibernate.
DB tables are:

```
events(event_id,name)
speaker(speaker_id,name)
event_speaker(event_id,speaker_id)
```

event.hbm.xml

```
<set name="speakers" table="event_speakers" cascade="save-update">
<key column="event_id"/>
<many-to-many class="com.manytomany.model.Speaker"/>
</set>
```

speaker.hbm.xml

```
<set name="events" table="event_speakers" cascade="save-update">
<key column="speaker_id"/>
<many-to-many class="com.manytomany.model.Event"/>
</set>
```

and i have implemented .equals and hashcode methods in Event.java and Speaker.java

Event.java

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Event event = (Event)obj;
    return this.id == event.id;
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return (int)id;
}
```

Speaker.java

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Speaker speaker = (Speaker)obj;
        return this.id == speaker.id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (int)id;
    }
```

here is my logic

```
        session.beginTransaction();
        Event event = (Event) session.createCriteria(Event.class).add(Restrictions.eq("id", 1L)).uniqueResult();
        event.setSpeakers(new HashSet());
        Speaker speaker = new Speaker();
        speaker.setName("11");
        Speaker speaker2 = new Speaker();
        speaker2.setName("12");

        event.getSpeakers().add(speaker);
        event.getSpeakers().add(speaker2);
        session.save(event);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
```

when i run above code hibernate is executing like this

```
Hibernate: select this_.event_id as event1_0_0_, this_.event_name as event2_0_0_ from events this_ where this_.event_id=?
Hibernate: select max(speaker_id) from speakers
Hibernate: insert into speakers (speaker_name, speaker_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: delete from event_speakers where event_id=?
Hibernate: insert into event_speakers (event_id, elt) values (?, ?)
```

why it is deleting from the join table, i want to insert new row instead of deleting in join table.

Comment: one event can have many speakers and one speaker can have many events.
so i have to insert a new row every time in join table, it working fine with new event, but if i want to add new speakers to existing event, row is deleting from join table and inserting with new speakers.
i want to insert new row with out deleting existing one in join table

Comment: Have you resolved the issue @RameshKotha ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your speakers are equal. I would investigate the boolean return value for

```
event.getSpeakers().add(speaker2);
```

My guess would be that the id of your speakers are null (the objects are still transient) when being checked for equality on addition to the set. Using the generated id for equality is dangerous for this reason.

One fix: get rid of the equals() and hashcode() methods on Event and Speaker.

Concern: With many to many sets, you run the risk of loading the entire database when loading a single entity. If you load a Speaker, it will fetch all that Speaker's Events, which in turn will fetch all those Event's Speakers...yikes. Even if you mark the collections for lazy loading, you make a minefield for people using them.

Another way: You could use composition and create an EventSpeaker entity around the event_speaker table. You would then create DAO and Service layers that provide you with the methods you need, like the ability to get all the Events for a Speaker and vice versa. It would also allow you to add properties unique to a SpeakerEvent combination, should that prove necessary.